# Differ NavLink Active for Same Link but Muliples Query Paramas Id

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Let's say I have a list of Ids array.

```
const items = [
   { id: 1, text='A' },
   { id: 2, text='B' },
   { id: 3, text='C' }
]
```

This is the Nav component.

```
export const NavigationItem = (props) =>
    <div className={classes.NavigationItem}>
        <NavLink
            style={style['normal']}
            to={props.link}
            exact={props.exact}
            activeClassName={classes.active}
        >{props.children}</NavLink>
    </div>
```

Here I use all created nav items. And I used Query params as id. When I render all nav items, it shows all nav items are active. But I want to show it as an active link that I clicked into.

```
items.map((item, index) => (
         <NavigationItem
             key={index}
             link={`/my-tasks?info_id=${item.id}`}
             text={item.text}
         />
))
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `useLocation` hook.

```
import {  useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const NavigationItem = (props) => {
   let location = useLocation();
   return (
   <div className={classes.NavigationItem}>
      <NavLink
          style={style['normal']}
          to={props.link}
          exact={props.exact}
          className={`nav-link ${location.pathname === ${props.link}? "active":""}`}>
     {props.children}
   </NavLink>
   </div>
   );
  };

  export default NavigationItem;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working fine now. But I have another small question. When I used the same pathname but different on query params id, It can not re-fetch data or re-render the related component automatically. Where is the problem?