# How can NavLink assign active separate with URL query string?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm working on a list of NavLink with different query string

```
  <ul>
    <li>
      <NavLink
        to="?type=all"
        end>
        all
      </NavLink>
    </li>
    <li>
      <NavLink
        to="?type=asdf"
        end>
        asdf
      </NavLink>
    </li>
    <li>
      <NavLink
        to="?type=1234"
        end>
        1234
      </NavLink>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

And I want to add some css on the active link, but I found that they all acitve all the same time because of they have same URL.

[Differ NavLink Active for Same Link but Muliples Query Paramas Id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69779655/differ-navlink-active-for-same-link-but-muliples-query-paramas-id)

I found a similiar question here and try the solution of useLocation(), but it doesn't work. So I log the value of props.to and location.pathname.

```
props.to: ?type=aaaaa
location.pathname: /console/products
```

The pathname just return the URL so it always return FALSE with compare to props.to, then I can't assign the active css class to the element.

Is it something changed in react-router-dom v6 or I make it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const {search} = useLocation()
const type = new URLSearchParams(search).get('type')

<NavLink
    to="?type=1234"
    // this is react-router-dom v6 way
    className={({isActive}) => (isActive && type === '1234') ? 'active' : ''}
    end
>
    1234
  </NavLink>
```

Comment: Great! You inspire me that I can compare the {search} and props.to to set the active class. How do you know that useLocation() have a search property? It didn't mention on the doc web.

Comment: It is written in typescript. Read their code. Your editor's intellisense may give you hints. Or simple console log the result to check what it gives you